# Connections leaking with state CLOSE_WAIT with java.net.HttpClient

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client, connection-leaks

We are using openJDK11.0.6 java.net.http HTTP (HTTP1.1) client to fetch content from websites. After a long execution time, we noticed a performance decrease. CPU is 100% used even when the app does nothing. We were able to determine that it comes from a lot of app leaked socket (CLOSE-WAIT state).

There is already some question about it here (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271192/connections-leaking-with-state-close-wait-with-httpclient)), but all submitted bugs are supposed to be fixed and backported to java 11.0.6.

I've been able to reproduce the bug into a minalist project [on github](https://github.com/navispeed/java11-closewait-socket). It seems it happens only when the client receives a 204 NO-CONTENT from the server.

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Version;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

public class BasicFetcherApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("App is running... pid: " + ProcessHandle.current().pid());
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(Version.HTTP_1_1).build();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      HttpRequest request =
          HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("http://localhost:4001/nocontent")).build();
      HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
      System.out.println(String.format("Response HTTP status: %s", response.statusCode()));
    }
    System.out.println("Finish");
    System.in.read();
  }
}
```

If we run it :

```
App is running... pid: 23306
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Response HTTP status: 204
Finish
```

```
ss -np | grep 23306
u_str            ESTAB                  0                   0                                                                                                 * 4121660                                                        * 0               users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=13))                                               
u_str            ESTAB                  0                   0                                                                                                 * 4121047                                                        * 0               users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=6))                                                
tcp              ESTAB                  0                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:56666                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:40177           users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=7))                                                
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58592                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=24))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58570                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=18))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58572                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=19))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58564                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=15))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58560                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=14))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58574                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=20))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58582                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=21))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58590                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=23))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58594                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=25))                                               
tcp              CLOSE-WAIT             1                   0                                                                                [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:58584                                         [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4001            users:(("java",pid=23306,fd=22))
```

OpenJDK bug (fixed):

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221395
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236596

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216974 which has been fixed in JDK 13